# Can't connect to Linksys E1200 router in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, internet, router

Ubuntu Studio 18.04 had corrupt file system issues on SDA1 hard drive and could not boot.  I booted from a DVD disk, ran fsck and corrected problems.  Since then I have not been able to access the router or internet. When booting up Ubuntu runs "autoethernet" and tells me it has an ethernet connection, but cannot see the router. Prior to the corrupt file system, Ubuntu never ran "autoethernet."

I've checked the ethernet cable between the computer and router and it is secure and port light on router is on. When I try configuring the router settings to correspond to the Win10 laptop settings, I am having no luck, and I have found very little documentation on how to configure the router connection.  One thing I have not found is anywhere to enter the router user password.

Any help as to properly reconfiguring my system will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What address are you being assigned? Show the output

```
ip address
```

Selected the “Automatically connect to this network when it is available” in the “General” tab?

Most routers can be reached with 192.168.1.1, 192.168.0.1 using a web browser. Even your phone. Default settings on routers are to assign each devices its own IP address (DHCP) So once you plug in a PC, within seconds and IP address gets assigned 192.168.1.5

If router doesn't assigned address then, acting on its APIPA protocol, it will assign itself the 169.254.0.0 IP. Basically not talking to eachother.

1. Reboot everything, better yet, turn off, unplug from wall, wait 1 min then start up.
2. replace cable and inspect connectors (black char marks could be lightning damage)
3. inspect ethernet ports for bent pins, debris, anything not right
4. try with a different ethernet connection: USB dongle, PCI card, PCIe, wifi
5. try a different Live distro. Ubuntu 16.04 or 20.04

Comment: The router works perfectly fine with my laptop, and has IP address 192.168.1.1. Logging to the IP I get the linksys connect control panel. On the linux desktop however, firefox tells me it is unable to establish a connection to 192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.0 or 192.168.1.5. I've replaced the cable twice and get port indicator lights at both the computer and router. I set up my router to require a password and user ID when I saw several computers and a smart TV connected through WiFi (none were mine). I can't find anyplace to enter the login credentials in Linux.

Comment: I've had compatibility issue with Firefox and routers web menu. Try installing a few different web browsers... Chromium, Midori, Brave, Vivaldi, Opera, Falkon, Konqueror, or any other not based on Firefox.

Comment: I've been searching for answers and trying various fixes. Since I lost the sudoers file when fixing the "orphaned INODES" problem on sda1, I have been trying to check the validity of the internal DNS lookup.  "ifconfig" points to 127.0.0.1 which would be the etherned adapter. "route -n" produced some odd results:                                           
maintenance@System-Product-Name:~$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
To me this looks like there is no internal DNS lookup.   HELP